# How to create and sign a transaction on a mobile device?

Tags: api, blockfrost, integration

I would like to create a simple mobile application (iOS) that would create and sign a transaction and submit it through an API like [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io) to the network. Preferably that transaction would interact with a smart contract address.

Is it currently possible to do that? I would suspect it is since it seems Yoroi works like that but how can this be done? I don't see any SDKs for iOS or Android that would enable such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure, you can use [Emurgo's serialization library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-nodejs) to create the transactions and [Blockfrost's Swift 5 SDK](https://github.com/blockfrost/blockfrost-swift) to submit it and fetch Cardano blockchain data.

[Yoroi-mobile project](https://github.com/Emurgo/yoroi-mobile) might be an inspiration.

Comment: Thanks those are helpful but I was looking for native iOS and Android SDKs. The serialization library is a Rust crate which cannot be easily used from a native app. It has bindings to Javascript and I see that Yoroi is a React Native app but I was looking for a Swift version of those.

Comment: Ah, sadly, I do not think native version exists at this moment.